# Today date not highlighted

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I made an simple application using jquery fullcalender.  But my today date is not highlighted.
But today button working fine. What can be the reason? in `basicWeek`, `basicDay` it's working

```
<?php
echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.7.1.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('ui.core.js');
echo $javascript->link('ui.resizable.js');
echo $javascript->link('fullcalendar.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('ui.draggable.js');
echo $html->css('fullcalendar');

?>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            }
    });
 });
</script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Can't do much without code...

Comment: The same works for me; see: http://jsfiddle.net/7Jbrz/ . Can you show me the issue? (i use 1.4.7 and you?)

Comment: Here with 1.5.3, works fine too http://jsfiddle.net/7Jbrz/1/

Comment: Give me more info please...for me it works.

Comment: Hi, have you more new about this?

Comment: The problem was css overriding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, It was css overwriting.